# Me aparece atribute Error. A que se debe?

Tags: python

tengo dos clases una se llama matrices y la otra ejecutarmatrices, el código debería de operar la matrices y colocar el resultado en una tercera matriz pero cuando le doy f5 puedo ingresar los números a las matrices pero cuando le toca operar me aparece:

> "Traceback (most recent call last):   File "clases y matrices.py",
>   line 24, in 
>       class ejecutarmatrices:   File "clases y matrices.py", line 36, in ejecutarmatrices
>       __matr3=objmatriz.obtenermatriz3()   File "clases y matrices.py", line 20, in obtenermatriz3
>       return self.__martriz3 AttributeError: 'matrices' object has no attribute '_matrices__martriz3'"

El código es el siguiente:

```
    #Clases y matrices.
class matrices:
    def __init__(self):
            self.__matriz1=[[0 for x in range(5)] for y in range(5)]
            self.__matriz2=[[0 for x in range(5)] for y in range(5)]
            self.__matriz3=[[0 for x in range(5)] for y in range(5)]            
    def establecermatriz1(self,mat1=[]):
            self.__matriz1=mat1
    def establecermatriz2(self,mat2=[]):
            self.__matriz2=mat2
    def calcularmatriz3(self):
            for r in range(0,5):
                    for c in range(0,5):
                            self.__matriz3[r][c]= self.__matriz1[r][c]+self.__matriz2[r][c]
    def obtenermatriz1(self):
            return self.__matriz1
    def obtenermatriz2(self):
            return self.__matriz2
    def obtenermatriz3(self):
            return self.__martriz3

#Se crea la clase ejecutar

class ejecutarmatrices:
    def __init__(self):
            self.__matr1=[[0 for x in range(5)] for y in range(5)]
            self.__matr2=[[0 for x in range(5)] for y in range(5)]
            self.__matr3=[[0 for x in range(5)] for y in range(5)]
    __matr1=[[input('digite un numero ') for x in range(5)] for y in range(5)]
    print ("ingrese los numero para la segunda matriz")
    __matr2=[[input('digite un numero ') for x in range(5)] for y in range(5)]
    objmatriz= matrices()
    objmatriz.establecermatriz1(__matr1)
    objmatriz.establecermatriz2(__matr2)
    objmatriz.calcularmatriz3()
    __matr3=objmatriz.obtenermatriz3()
    print("matriz número uno")
    for r in range(0,5):
              print ("\n")
              for c in range(0,5):
                      print (__matr1[r][c])
    print("matriz número dos")
    for r in range(0,5):
              print("\n")
              for c in range(0,5):
                      print (__matr2[r][c])
    print("matriz número tres (operaciones) ")
    for r in range(0,5):
              print("\n")
              for c in range(0,5):
                      print(__matr3[r][c])
```

Comment: Has escrito martriz3 en vez de matriz3

Comment: Joder, gracias por todo ya se solucionó.